# oledbException was unhandled error appering

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to populate a text box with a forename and surname using the code below:

```
using (OleDbConnection connName = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
            {

                String sqlName = "SELECT forename, Surname FROM customer WHERE [customerID]=" + txtCustomerID.Text;

                // Create a command to use to call the database.
                OleDbCommand commandname = new OleDbCommand(sqlName, connName);
                 connName.Open();
                // Create a reader containing the results


                using (OleDbDataReader readerName = commandname.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    readerName.Read(); // Advance to the first row.
                    txtName.Text = readerName[0].ToString();
                }
                connName.Close();                 

             }
```

However I'm getting the error: `OleDbException` was unhandled.

> "no required values for one of more required parameters"

at the `ExecuteReader` and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

EDIT: this code below is nearly the exact same bar for the information in the query but this exception is not coming up for it.

```
  string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.PID2dbConnectionString;

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
        {
            String sqlPoints = "SELECT points FROM customer WHERE [customerID]=" + txtCustomerID.Text;
            conn.Open();

            // Create a command to use to call the database.
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlPoints, conn);
            // Create a reader containing the results

            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read(); // Advance to the first row.
                txtPoints.Text = reader[0].ToString(); // Read the contents of the first column
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Is txtCustomerID.text null?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line gives you this error?

Comment: @SonerGönül - I believe the OP said it was this line:  `using (OleDbDataReader readerName = commandname.ExecuteReader())`

Comment: yes it is that line, when i remove the brackets around the "CustomerID" i get the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason for this is a null or empty string i.e. txtCustomerID.Text has no value so the query being sent to the server is:

```
SELECT forename, Surname FROM customer WHERE [customerID]=
```

You can avoid errors like this and [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), use strongly typed parameters and avoid data truncation using parameterised queries (I have assumed customer ID is an int field)

```
    using (OleDbConnection connName = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
    {
        String sqlName = "SELECT forename, Surname FROM customer WHERE customerID = @CustomerID";

        // Create a command to use to call the database.
        using (OleDbCommand commandname = new OleDbCommand(sqlName, connName))
        {

            //Check the input is valid
            int customerID = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(txtCustomerID.Text, out customerID))
            {
                txtName.Text = "Customer ID Text box is not an integer";
                return;
            }


            connName.Open();

            // Add the parameter to the command
            commandname.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = customerID;

            // Create a reader containing the results
            using (OleDbDataReader readerName = commandname.ExecuteReader())
            {
                readerName.Read(); // Advance to the first row.
                txtName.Text = readerName[0].ToString();
            }
            connName.Close();                 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode parameters used in string queries.

```
  String sqlName = String.Format("SELECT forname, Surname FROM customer WHERE customerID={0}",txtCustomerID.Text);
```

But I advice you against using SQL queries hard-coded in strings. Its easy way for SQL Injection attack. You should use parammeters instead.

Comment: im still getting the same error when I replace this with my current sql,

Comment: Could you debug and post value of sqlName variable after assignment?

Comment: After debugging the sqlName is "Null" which is the problem i take it? im verynew to c# and sql in general.

Comment: But is it null after the line String sqlName =... executes?

Comment: the line after it is  "SELECT forname, Surname FROM customer WHERE [customerID]='112'" which shows in the sql name value window

Comment: I guess if customerID is numeric, you don't need '. The error you got means one of the identifiers in your query is not recognized. Maybe try removing [ ] brackets.

Comment: without the brackets i am now getting "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: I edited the answer - try it now (before i thought that CustomerID is not numeric var)

Comment: just tried it, im now getting "Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'customerID=System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 111'."